# What is the meaning of pygo and pagus in the word pygopagus?

Tags: terminology, etymology

I know definition of the disease pygopagus but I want to know the meaning of separate parts of it, in fact what's the meaning of *pygo-* and *-pagus* in terminology?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of ethymology and should be asked on [english.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com). Note also, that biology is not medicine anyway. So,if you were looking for a definition of this disease, you should ask on [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Firs of all, etymology not ethymology! as I mentioned I know the definition so I am not looking for the definition of disease! and as far as I know prefix and suffixes are studied in terminology, so I wanted to ask that is pagus a suffix or not?

Comment: First of all, First not Firs! Joking... thanks for correcting me on that. I'm sorry if you thought I said you were looking for a definition. I said `if you were looking for a definition of this disease, you should ask on Health.SE`. It was only indicative. Terminology (study of the terms of their use) questions (about terms used in biology) are on-topic. I don't think etymology questions (the study of the origin of words) are on-topic. I am voting to close. I think your question would be on-topic on english.SE or maybe [linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Gr: Pygo/pyge (tail, rump) + pagus (fixed). Any decent dictionary will give you the etymology of the word.

Comment: FWIW Pygé is not "tail" (that's oura). Pygé means ass (or arse in British English), and it's a vulgar term in Ancient Greek.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wiktionary.com](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pygopagus):

- ***pygo-*** means "rump" or "posterior" from Ancient Greek πυγή (pugḗ, “tail, rump”).

According to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-pagus):

- ***-pagus*** means "fixation" or "something fixed or solid" from Greek  págos.

So literally, **pygopagus** (or conjoined twins attached at the butt) means "fixed rumps".